# Scrapy: How would I add an item that numbers entries in my CSV output?

Tags: scrapy

I need to include an item in my spider `(item['number'] = ... )` that just assigns a number to each scraped row in my CSV output file in ascending order.

So the "number" column would assign a 1 to the first row, a 2 to the second row and so on. How would I code the item to return this in a way that returns incrementations of +1 each time?

*In case your wondering, I need to use the number column as a Dim Primary Key for a cube database.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want the number to be part of the item generation process and output, then you can use a [Pipeline](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html).

`settings.py`

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    "myspider.pipelines.NumberPipeline": 300,
}
```

`pipelines.py`

```
class NumberPipeline(object):
    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.number = 1 # The starting number.

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        item['number'] = self.number
        self.number += 1
        return item
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked well for me. Really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

When you will read your csv file, you can use `enumerate` like:

```
import csv

with open('file.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for i, row in enumerate(reader, start=1):
        print(i)
```